# Render Different View (template) for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm trying to do a conditional render of a different template from ActionMailer (Rails 3.1.1). I want most users to get the normal `welcome.html.erb` template, but some users to get the special `welcome_photographer.html.erb` template. This type of thing works in ActionController:

```
# (in /app/mailers/user_mailer.rb) 
def welcome(user)
  @user = user
  mail(:to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", :subject => "Welcome to ...")
  render "welcome_photographer" if @user.is_photographer
end
```

But the render doesn't work -- everyone gets the standard `welcome.html.erb` even if `@user.is_photographer == true`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You shouldn't try to do anything after you call `mail()`.  However, to choose another template, you should pass `:template_name` as an option.  For example:

```
template = @user.is_photographer ? "welcome_photographer" : "welcome"
mail(:to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", 
     :subject => "Welcome to ...", 
     :template_name => template)
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer by now, but I found it today. Should `:template_name => template` instead be `:template_name => "template"`? I tried it your way and ended up going to the docs which show it as a string.

Comment: `template` is a variable that is set to a string on the first line. Based on whether the user is a photographer or not, `template` is either `"welcome_photographer"` or `"welcome"`.

Comment: See here for an up to date information on this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views

Answer (score 10):

Funny in rails 3.2.14 This does NOT work for me:

```
mail(:to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", :subject => "Welcome to ...") do |format|
  format.html { render 'templatename' }
end
```

However this does:

```
mail(:to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", 
 :subject => "Welcome to ...", 
:template_name => template)
```

Comment: I found the block with the `do` and `format.html` helped when rendering from another subdirectory that doesn't belong to the mailer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The solution from Sean Hill doesn't work for me (Rails 3.2+). `template_name` seems to be ignored. What worked for me is something like this:

```
mail(:to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", :subject => "Welcome to ...") do |format|
  format.html { render 'templatename' }
end
```

Comment: This method also lets you set absolute paths in the views dir which template_name does not seem to allow.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `template_name` you also have to pass `template_path` as an argument where path is the directory name under `app/views` directory, for example:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email
    @user = params[:user]
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site',
         template_path: 'notifications',
         template_name: 'another')
  end
end
```

Docs link:
`https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html`