# How to use remote/dynamic HTML templates in Actionmailer - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have a use-case where our email templates are designed by end-users and uploaded on cloud (AWS S3) as HTML. Now while sending emails, I basically want the mailers to use HTMLs from S3 using something like `remote_url` in actionmailer's methods.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think the the lack of cases where it is a good idea to make a http request during rendering an email is the reason this does not exist. I would pull down the file to disk (to a user specific dir) and treat it as a 'normal template'

Comment: @AxelTetzlaff To elaborate more on the use case: We have a SaaS platfrom where enterprises can design their own emails (to be sent to their customers). We use a plugin/editor for this, which uploads the HTML to S3, which should ideally be used to send emails. The problem with pulling down the file to disk is that rails doesn't pick dynamic (changes in files) files in production environment. It loads all the templates on boot.

Comment: I doubt that it loads all of them at boot time. That would mean it would actually have to execute the mailer actions since you can specify a custom template like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219179/render-different-view-template-for-actionmailer It is more a cache. And that you can trick by generating new template names each time. However that will probably eat up all your memory

Comment: So sadly I guess there is no simple solution and you have to place your own implementation of https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionview/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L145 which you can customize to download a file first.